# How to add extra hash variables when running reports in nuBuilderPro?

Tags: php, web-applications

I need some extra data to print on my reports, other than the default objects (fields, labels and images), but I can't figure out how to add some extra variables. 
In nuBuilderPro, is there a way to manually add extra hash variables that can be used when running a report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nuSetHash() to set a Hash variable that will carry through to the next Form or PHP code you want to run.

```
nuSetHash('newTotal', document.getElementById('newTotal').value);   //-- javascript

print 'The new Total is : #newTotal#';   //-- php
```